# Vue.js v-bind:value not dsplaying the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The `v-bind:value"email"` isn't displaying mike@example.com in the input box?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: 'mike@example.com',
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button type="submit" v-bind:value="email" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `input` box ? I am just seeing submit type `button` here  ?

Comment: If you inspect the snippet, it's setting the `value` attribute correctly

Answer (score 1):

You want the submit button to be labeled "mike@example.com"?

... then you can use an input element (type="submit") and give it a value:

```html
<input type="submit" v-bind:value="email" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

...or you use a button then you have to put the text to display between the opening and closing tags

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{email}}</button>
```

Also note the data-attribute in vue should be a method not an object ([read more here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-does-data-need-to-be-a-function)):

```js
  data() {
    return {
      email: 'mike@example.com'
    }
  }
```

Comment: oh bother, I put the damn ting in the wrong place, my bad. Stared at it for an hour, and didnt see it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <button >{{email}}</button>
        <input type="submit" :value="email">
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script >
    new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                email: 'mike@example.com',
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```